# grunt-postcss autoprefixer not adding prefixes

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, autoprefixer, postcss

I'm trying to use grunt-postcss with autoprefixer for the first time but the css is not getting prefixed. 
I do get the message

```
Running "postcss:dist" (postcss) task
>> 1 processed stylesheet created.

Done, without errors.
```

but nothing is being prefixed.

To make sure the problem wasn't my css I created a file called `test.css` with only

```
html {display:flex;}
```

and added different combination of browsers to try and trigger the prefixes, but to no avail.

Here is what the task looks like right now:

```
postcss: {
  options: {
    processsors: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: [
          'last 8 versions'
        ]
      })
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
      'src/css/prefixed/test.css':'src/css/test.css'
    }
  }
}
```

The task is registered as

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['postcss:dist']);
```

Adding '*.postcss*' to the `require` line doesn't have any effect (I've seen this used here and there) and neither does replacing the `files` property with

```
src: 'src/css/test.css',
dest: 'src/css/prefixed/test.css'
```

If I delete the 'prefixed' folder and run grunt, the folder does get created and the new file is in there, just not prefixed at all.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You have an extra `s` in `processors`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Ben!